# Which is better? "Ans to the q-1" or "The ans to q-1"

Tags: sentence, sentence-patterns

Upto high school, before answering any question in the exam we used to write "Ans to the q-no:1" (Answer to the question number 1). But then our English teacher told us to write "The ans to q-no:1" (The answer to question number 1). Most students use the former though. Which one is better/grammatically correct?

Edit: We use these acronyms because writing the whole sentence is cumbersome since we have to write it so often. Teachers are used to such acronyms.

Comment: How strange. The second is more grammatically correct, but I would write "Question 1"  and not some wierd code. In an examination it should be obvious I am answering that question, not asking one. Please, don't follow the teacher's bad example by using abbreviations throughout the answer.

Comment: This seems like it's something specific to your teacher, school, or school system.  I've never heard of anything like that, having been married to a 25-year veteran teacher, worked on school district software for 15 years, had three kids go through the public schools here, and currently running for a seat on the Board of Education.  So, basically, I would say it's a case of "do what your told, even if it's wrong."

Comment: Also, since neither is standard English nor a complete sentence, neither is really grammatically correct (or incorrect).

Comment: What @RogerSinasohn said. How sad that people who want to learn English have to put up with such ignorant teachers.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is in English so whichever one the teacher wants you to use, I'm having trouble with the fact that your English teacher didn't demand the full sentence "the answer to question [number] is:".

Answer (score 0):

Well, your English teacher is correct on using article 'The'.

Go for below format, if she recommends

> The ans to q-no:1

But remember, this patter is not universally recognised. It is just local to your school.

The correct format is:

> **The answer to question no.1**  or **The answer to question #1**

Comment: Or "The answer to the first question [is ...]"  Consider also "The answer to Question 1 [is ...], or even "Question 1's answer [is ...]"